# CIL nuget package does not contain Sdl.AudienceManager.ContentDelivery.dll

Tags: web8, audience-manager, installation

i'm currently setting up a website using Web 8 and Audience Manager.
Following the installation manual, we need to import the CIL nuget package into our visual studio solution (http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v1/GUID-D37642DE-017F-4B9B-B063-CDD795642E9E).

I did that, but one of the next steps of the installation manual says this :

> If you are adding the Role to a .NET Web site, and you have chosen not
>   to reference the online Content Interaction Libraries (CILs) on Nuget
>   from your Visual Studio project, copy the contents of the dotNet\bin\
>   subfolder to the Web site's bin\ folder on your target machine.

As I used the nuget package, I would expect to find all dlls from the bin subfolder referenced in my solution. However, it looks like the dll "Sdl.AudienceManager.ContentDelivery.dll" is missing (it is in the bin folder of the tridion installer files, but not in the nuget package).

Does this mean the nuget package is not correct, or is there a mistake in the documentation ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I downloaded the latest nuget package Sdl.Web.Cil version 8.1.1 (released 5th April) and I do get the Sdl.AudienceManager.ContentDelivery reference in there:

[image]

If that isn't working for you could try installing the SDL Web Audience Manager nuget package directly:

[image]

Comment: It looks like it is indeed in the nuget package. I just retried to install the package on a fresh web app. The Dll is indeed in the package, but it's never referenced in the project. Is this something that you need to do manually if you need to use it ?